# Is it possible to use recaptcha with auth0 in some way to avoid having a user to sign in but still have a token?

Tags: oauth, architecture, recaptcha

I have an app, client side, that uses auth0 for accessing the different API's on the server. But now I want to add another app, a single page app, I'm going to use VueJs, and this app would be open "ideally" w/o a user having to sign in, it's like a demo with reduced functionality, I just want to check that the user is not a robot basically, so I don't expose my API in those cases.

My ideas so far:
 - Somehow use recaptcha and auth0 altogether.
 - Then have a new server that would validate that the calls are made only to allowed endpoints (this is not of my interest in the question), so that even if somehow the auth is vulnerated it doesn't leave the real server open to all type of calls.
 - Pass the call to the server along with the bearer token, just as if I was doing it with my other old client app.

Is this viable? Now I'm forcing the user to validate, this is more a thing about UX (User-experience), but I'd like a way to avoid that. I'm aware that just with auth0 I can't do this [see this post from Auth0](https://community.auth0.com/t/can-i-get-auth0-to-generate-a-generic-access-token-if-the-user-has-not-logged-in/7988), so I was expecting a mix between what I mentioned.

EDIT:
I'm sticking to validating in both cases, but I'm still interested to get opinions over this as future references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end, with the very concept of how auth0 works that idea is not possible, so my approach was the following:
Give a temporary authenticated (auth 0) visitor a token which has restricted access level, then pass the request to a new middle server, the idea is to encrypt the real ids so the frontend thinks it's requesting project A123456etc, when indeed it's going to get decrypted in the middle server to project 456y-etc and given a whitelist it will decide to pass the request along with the token to the final server, the final server has measures to reduce xss and Ddos threats.

Anyway, if there's a better resolve to it I will change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a mix of using recaptcha for the open public, then on the server side analyse the incoming user request (you can already try to get a human made digital fingerprint just to differentiate with a robot-generated one) and the server (more a middle server) makes the call to you API (and this server has limited surface access)

Answer (score 0):

What we normally do in these situations (if I got your issue correctly) is to create two different endpoints, one working with the token and another one receiving the Recaptcha token and validating it with Google servers.

Both endpoints end up calling the same code but this way you can add extra functionality in a layer in the 'public' endpoint to ensure that you are asking only for public features (if that cannot be granted just modifying the interface).